# How can I use background image in input checkbox?

Tags: css

I want to use background image in checkbox. I have tried something but it doesn't work. I am trying the following.

/* css */

```
.common_pic input[type=checkbox] {
 background: url("images/checkbox.png") no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 height: 27px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 29px;
 width: 27px;
 }
```

HTML

```
      <div class="common_pic">           
  development
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to hide the checkbox altogether (with `display: none` or more appropriately `visibility: hidden;`), and use a `<label>` element with a background image to toggle the states.

You'll still need to use some sort of JavaScript to change the background when the checkbox's state changes. (As there is no "parent selector" in CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You can't: the browser uses system API to draw checkboxes, it simply doesn't support backgrounds.

You can do some workaround, i.e. to set `opacity: 0` on the checkbox and draw checked/unchecked image behind it.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox - Yes, those are checkboxes.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: no - those are not checkboxes: jQuery UI replaces them for spans, it's just another workaround. It can't be done with CSS as the OP asks.

Comment: OP never said he wanted a *pure* CSS solution, it's true, it can't be done cleanly and perfectly in pure CSS, you can get close, but with trivial touches of JavaScript it's perfectly possible even without the span.

Comment: Also, the linked duplicate suggests otherwise

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: he specified the `css` tag only. But wow, the answer in the duplicate is brilliant!